# Type signature in a where clause

Tags: haskell, enumerator, parametric-polymorphism

I've written a function similar to `Data.Enumerator.List.map` that makes an `Iteratee` compatible with an `Enumerator` that feeds a different `Stream` type.

`import Data.Enumerator`

```
test :: Monad m => (ao -> ai) -> Iteratee ai m b -> Iteratee ao m b
test f iter = go $$ iter
   where go (Continue k) = continue $
            \stream -> go $$ k (fmap f stream)
         go (Yield res _) = yield res EOF
```

If I omit the type signature for `go`, this will work just fine.
However, I'd like to include it but I'm unable to determine what the correct signature should be.
Here's what I think it should be:

`go :: Monad m => Step ai m b -> Iteratee ao m b`

but that doesn't work.
I need some advice on finding the correct type signature for `go`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably can't give `go` a type signature as-is.

The reason for this is that it makes use of polymorphic arguments bound by `test`. This means that, inside `go`, the identifier `f` has type `(ao -> ai)` for *some specific, but unknown* types `ao` and `ai`.

Type variables are generally only in scope for the single type signature where they're introduced, so when you give `go` its own type signature, the `ao` and `ai` there are new, polymorphic types, which of course causes a type error when trying to combine them with the similarly named, but fixed (and unknowable) types from `test`'s signature.

The end result is that you can't write the type of `go` explicitly, which is not very satisfying. To solve this, GHC offers [the ScopedTypeVariables extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables), which allows bringing variables introduced in a type signature in scope inside the `where` clause of the function, among other things.

Note that if you only use the `where` clause to create an internal scope for definitions, and don't make use of identifiers bound by arguments to the outer function, you can write type signatures in the `where` clause just like you can for top level bindings. If you don't want to use GHC extensions, you can simply pass the parameters in redundantly. Something like this should work in that case:

```
test :: Monad m => (ao -> ai) -> Iteratee ai m b -> Iteratee ao m b
test f iter = go f $$ iter
  where go :: Monad m => (ao -> ai) -> Step ai m b -> Iteratee ao m b
        go f (Continue k) = continue $
             \stream -> go f $$ k (fmap f stream)
        go _ (Yield res _) = yield res EOF
```

Comment: @hammar: Thanks. I swear I make a dumb typo every time I put more than four lines of code in an answer without loading them in GHCi first. Sigh...

Answer (score 9):

You probably want that type, but with the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension enabled and with the variables from `test`'s type signature in scope:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Enumerator
test :: forall m ai ao b. Monad m => (ao -> ai) -> Iteratee ai m b -> Iteratee ao m b
test f iter = go $$ iter
   where go :: Step ai m b -> Iteratee ao m b
         go (Continue k) = continue $
            \stream -> go $$ k (fmap f stream)
         go (Yield res _) = yield res EOF
```

See the [GHC documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables) for more information.

Comment: N.B. -- Observe that there's no `Monad m` constraint here in `go`'s type, unlike the proposed type in the question. This is important, because not only is the same `m` in scope, the *class constraint* is also still in scope.

Comment: ...though it would probably work fine if you did add the constraint in. It would just be particularly easy for GHC to find an instance.

Comment: It does. You could also add `Monad Maybe`, `m ~ m`, or any other trivial constraint to the context, and GHC will accept it without complaint. It warns about `(Monad m, Monad m, Monad m) =>` though.

Comment: Being new to `ScopedTypeVariables`, adding `forall m ai ao b.` to the outer function `test` was the critical part I was missing. Thanks!