# Type Specification in a Where Clause

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to do something very simple as part of a homework. All I need to do is write a function that takes in a list of 2-tuples of numbers representing base and height lengths for triangles, and return a list of the areas corresponding to those triangles. One of the requirements is that I do that by defining a function and declaring its type in a `where` clause. Everything I've tried so far fails to compile, here's what I've got:

```
calcTriangleAreas xs = [triArea x | x<-xs]
    where triArea:: (Num, Num) -> Num --this uses 4 preceding spaces 
triArea (base, height) = base*height/2
```

This fails with the error `The type signature for ‘triArea’ lacks an accompanying binding`, which to me sounds like triArea is not defined inside of the where-clause. Okay, so let's indent it to match the `where`:

```
calcTriangleAreas xs = [triArea x | x<-xs]
    where triArea:: (Num, Num) -> Num --this uses 4 preceding spaces 
    triArea (base, height) = base*height/2 --... and so does this
```

This one fails to compile the particularly uninformative error message `parse error on input triArea`. Just for fun, let's try indenting it a bit more, because idk what else to do:

```
calcTriangleAreas xs = [triArea x | x<-xs]
    where triArea:: (Num, Num) -> Num --this uses 4 preceding spaces 
        triArea (base, height) = base*height/2 --this has 8
```

but, no dice, fails with the same `parse error` message. I tried replacing the spacing in each of these with equivalent, 4-space tabs, but that didn't
help. The first two produce the same errors with tabs as with spaces, but the last one, shown here:

```
calcTriangleAreas xs = [triArea x | x<-xs]
    where triArea:: (Num, Num) -> Num --this uses a preceding tab character 
        triArea (base, height) = base*height/2 --this has 2
```

gives the error message

```
Illegal type signature: ‘(Num, Num) -> Num triArea (base, height)’
  Perhaps you intended to use ScopedTypeVariables
In a pattern type-signature
```

and I have no idea what that's trying to say, but it seems to be ignoring newlines all of a sudden. I've been reading through "Learn You a Haskell", and I'm supposed to be able to do this with the information presented in the first three chapters, but I've scoured those and they never specify the type of a functioned defined in a `where` clause in those chapters. For the record, their examples seem to be irreverent of spacing, and I copied the style of one of them:

```
calcTriangleAreas xs = [triArea x | x<-xs]
    where triArea:: (Num, Num) -> Num --4 preceding spaces
          triArea (base, height) = base*height/2 --10 preceding spaces
```

but this also failed to compile, spitting out the utterly incomprehensible error message:

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘Num’
    The first argument of a tuple should have kind ‘*’,
      but ‘Num’ has kind ‘* -> GHC.Prim.Constraint’
    In the type signature for ‘triArea’: triArea :: (Num, Num) -> Num
    In an equation for ‘calcTriangleAreas’:
        calcTriangleAreas xs
          = [triArea x | x <- xs]
          where
              triArea :: (Num, Num) -> Num
              triArea (base, height) = base * height / 2
```

I can't find anything when I google/hoogle it, and I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928884/type-signature-in-a-where-clause), but not only is it showing haskell far too
advanced for me to read, but based on the content I don't believe they're having the same problem as me. I've tried specifying the type of `calcTriangleAreas`, and I've tried aliasing the types in the specification for `triArea` to be `Floating` and frankly I'm at the end of my rope. The top line of my file is `module ChapterThree where`, but beyond that the code I've shown in every example is the entire file.

I'm working on 32-bit Linux Mint 18, and I'm compiling with `ghc ChapterThree.hs Chapter3UnitTests.hs -o Test`, where ChapterThree.hs is my file and the unit tests are given by my teacher so I can easily tell if my program works (It never gets to the compilation step for ChapterThreeUnitTests.hs, so I didn't think the content would be important), and my ghc version is 7.10.3.

EDIT: Note that if I just remove the type specification altogether, everything compiles just fine, and that function passes all of its associated unit tests.

Please, save me from my madness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last example is correct, but the type you wrote doesn't make sense. `Num` is a **class constraint** not a type. You probably wanted to write:

```
calcTriangleAreas xs = [triArea x | x<-xs]
    where triArea:: Num a => (a, a) -> a
          triArea (base, height) = base*height/2
```

The rule is: assignments must be aligned.

Moreover `(/)` requires the `Fractional` class:

```
calcTriangleAreas xs = [triArea x | x<-xs]
    where triArea:: Fractional a => (a, a) -> a
          triArea (base, height) = base*height/2
```

---

Note that the indentation level is **not** related in any way with the indentation level of the `where`. For example you could write that code in this way:

```
calcTriangleAreas xs = [triArea x | x<-xs] where
    triArea:: Fractional a => (a, a) -> a
    triArea (base, height) = base*height/2
```

The indentation level is defined by the first assignment in a `where`/`let` or the first line of a `do` block. All the other lines must align with that one.

So all of these are correct:

```
f x = y where
  a = b
  y = ...

f x = y
  where a = b
        y = ...

f x = y
  where
    a = b
    y = ...
```

Comment: So does tabs/spaces not matter? Also: maaaan, I tried that but with `Floating` instead of `Fractional` and it just threw up at me. Anyway, thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: @bfieck please don't use tabs. Use two spaces per indent. Everyone will be much happier with you :-)

Comment: @bfieck Tabs are not a good way of indenting code for indentation-sensitive languages. There's *plenty* of people that have trouble with some error due to that because mixing tabs and spaces when using tab indentation is extremely easy and catastrophic. Also: the compiler considers a tab as 8 spaces, but your editor probably consider it as either 2 or 4, which means what you see in the editor is probably not what the compiler sees which increases the chances of errors. There was even a proposal to completely disallow tabs for indentation in Haskell.

Comment: Why would the compiler turn tabs into sequences of spaces? Imo, tabs are inherently superior for indentation. If you like two-space indents, you can set your editor to render them as such; everyone can have their own, preferred layout without causing any physical differences in the files. Obviously that doesn't work for haskell, cuz the assignments have to be aligned, but if you ask me, haskell just shouldn't enforce a style guide as part of the language specification.

Comment: The use of tabs is discouraged precisely *because* Haskell does not enforce any particular amount of indentation at any level. Because tabs could be displayed as different amounts of whitespace by different users, the *apparent* indentation may differ from the *actual* indentation.

Comment: No I get that, but it seems like if you just parse tab characters instead of turning them into spaces, and be a little more stringent about the placement of assignments relative to scoping keywords, the problem disappears. Just read the actual file instead of turning into something other than what I typed.

Comment: @bfieck When one mixes tab and spaces, in most editors it is easy to look at code which seems to be properly indented, when it's not. Historically, the Haskell 98 committee decided that tabs count as 8 spaces when checking indentation. A more stringent requirement would have been better. Today, GHC warns you if you use tabs. There are [good proposals](http://dmwit.com/tabs/) but most of the community decided that avoiding tabs is simpler in the long run.

Comment: Using *only* tabs would be worse, because now my indentation has to be indented by the same amount at each level, with no regard to the construct that initiated the indentation. The second and following lines of a `let` expression are often indented 4 spaces, while those of a `where` expression are indented by 6 spaces. Many people align type signatures with one type per line, with the indentation specified by the length of the function name; similar logic is applied to data types defined with record syntax. No fixed tab size will accommodate that style.

Comment: Tabs work for *indent levels*. They work great as long as you *only* use tabs for indentation, never mixing with spaces. But as soon as you start trying to line things up (such as indent to opening parenthesis) then *correct* indentation *requires* mixing tabs and spaces. They're just a bad idea IMHO even in C or python like syntax; why do we need the ability for each user to independently customise one tiny part of code style when everything else has to be agreed? And Haskell doesn't use indent levels, it uses alignment, so there's no getting away from needing a tab/space exchange rate.

Answer (score 0):

> spitting out the utterly incomprehensible error message:
>
> ```
> Expecting one more argument to ‘Num’
>    The first argument of a tuple should have kind ‘*’,
>      but ‘Num’ has kind ‘* -> GHC.Prim.Constraint’
> ```

To complement Bakuriu's answer, let me decode that for you.

The error says that -- line by line:

- `Num` is expecting one more argument -- we should write `Num a` from some `a`
- A tuple type such as `(,)` expects a type as argument. The statement "should have kind `*`" means "should be a type". The kinding system of Haskell associates `*` as the "kind of types". We have e.g. `Int :: *`, `String :: *`, and `(Maybe Char, [Int]) :: *`. Unary type constructors such as `Maybe` and `[]` are not types, but functions from types to types. We write `Maybe :: *->*` and `[] :: *->*`. Their kind `*->*` makes it possible to state that, since `Maybe :: *->*` and `Char :: *`, we have `Maybe Char :: *` ("is a type") similarly to ordinary value-level functions. The pair type constructor has kind `(,) :: *->*->*`: it expects two types and provides a type.
- `Num` has kind `*-> Constraint`. This means that, for every type `T`, the kind of `Num T` will be `Constraint`, which is not `*` as `(,)` expects. This triggers a kind error. The kind `Constraint` is given to typeclass constraints such as `Eq Int`, `Ord Bool`, or `Num Int`. These are not types, but are requirements on types. When we use `(+) :: Num a => a->a->a` we see that `(+)` works on any type `a`, as long as that type satisfies `Num a`, i.e. is numeric. Since `Num T` is not a type, we can not write `Maybe (Num T)` or `[Num T]`, we can only write e.g. `Maybe a` and require in the context that `a` belongs to typeclass `Num`.